# Update SQL Server 2000 database from LDF

Tags: sql-server-2000, logging

Just had a  disk and raid failure on the drives holding the our live databases. The log files (.ldf) are on a separate disk array and are OK (I think).

I've recovered the databases from the most recent backup however my question is can I use the logs (LDF files) to update the databases to the most recent point?

It's a Sindows 2003 box running SQL Server 2000 Standard edition.

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

You'd need log backups to apply to your full backup.

Don't try to replace the new LDF (created from restore) with the one you've recovered. It won't work because the internal ID and log state (LSN) will not match.

Basically, MDF/LDF files and backup files are unrelated to each other.